# symfony routing problems with index.php

Tags: frameworks, symfony1

I have a site built in symfony.

However, I'm putting some routing rules :

```
resgister:
url:     /register
param:   { module: register, action: index }
```

and I put a link :

```
link_to('register - here','register')
```

but this link points to http://www.mydomain.com/register
instead of http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/register

so I get an 404 error.

this problem occours only on production env, and not on development env.

any ideas ?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Because [`no_script_name`](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_2/en/04-Settings#chapter_04_sub_no_script_name) setting is set to "on" in production env.

Answer (score 3):

There's a misspelling in your YML file:

```
resgister:
  url:     /register
  param:   { module: register, action: index }
```

should be

```
register:
  url:     /register
  param:   { module: register, action: index }
```

Use with:

```
echo link_to('register - here','@register');
```

This should fix the 404. The no_script_name is the reasons you don't see index.php as stated in several other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to uncomment this line `RewriteBase /` in your /web/.htaccess file

```
# uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
# getting no_script_name to work
#RewriteBase /
```

That will probably help :)

I assume you have the apache [rewrite_module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) enabled

Comment: I thought he wants not to use `no_script_name`

Comment: Or he might just wondering why he gets the links without the index.php - and you're right because of the no_script_name setting

But the reason for 404 error is that he might have a badly set up mod_rewrite. Otherwise the change in .htaccess could solve it.